# Scrape items from an HTML list

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, xpath, page-objects, page-factory

When `Catalog` receives a fragment for a [book category](http://books.toscrape.com/), it seems to my eyes, to be just list items.  For space, I didn't include that output.  How can I ensure that only categories which belong to the catalog are passed to the `Category` instances which `Catalog` creates?

debug output for the [project](https://github.com/THUFIR/com.toscrape.books.selenium):

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/com.toscrape.books.selenium$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/com.toscrape.books.selenium$ gradle clean run

> Task :run
1546177894344   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" "-marionette" "--headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.64P2JcqFPQGb"
*** You are running in headless mode.
1546177894956   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: resource://pdf.js/
1546177894956   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: about:reader*
1546177898508   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 41957
1546177898575   Marionette      WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:38 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript warning: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js, line 1: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:44 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog iterateCatalogElements
INFO: trying to iterate..
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:45 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog iterateCatalogElements
INFO: li
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:45 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog iterateCatalogElements
INFO: Books
Travel
...
Cultural
Erotica
Crime
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:45 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Category <init>
INFO: new category..
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:45 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Category <init>
INFO: 
            <a href="index.html">Home</a>

Dec 30, 2018 5:51:45 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog iterateCatalogElements
INFO: li
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:45 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog iterateCatalogElements
INFO: Historical Fiction
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:45 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Category <init>
INFO: new category..
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:45 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Category <init>
INFO: 
                        <a href="catalogue/category/books/travel_2/index.html">

                                Travel

                        </a>



..                        
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog iterateCatalogElements
INFO: li
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog iterateCatalogElements
INFO: Cultural
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Category <init>
INFO: new category..
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Category <init>
INFO: 
                        <a href="catalogue/category/books/health_47/index.html">

                                Health

                        </a>


Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog iterateCatalogElements
INFO: li
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog iterateCatalogElements
INFO: A Light in the ...
£51.77
In stock
Add to basket
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Category <init>
INFO: new category..
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Category <init>
INFO: 
                        <a href="catalogue/category/books/erotica_50/index.html">

                                Erotica

                        </a>


Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog iterateCatalogElements
INFO: li
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog iterateCatalogElements
INFO: Sharp Objects
£47.82
In stock
Add to basket
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Category <init>
INFO: new category..
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Category <init>
INFO: 






    <article class="product_pod">

            <div class="image_container">


..

Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog iterateCatalogElements
INFO: li
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog iterateCatalogElements
INFO: The Dirty Little Secrets ...
£33.34
In stock
Add to basket
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Category <init>
INFO: new category..
Dec 30, 2018 5:51:46 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Category <init>
INFO: 




..


    <form>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-loading-text="Adding...">Add to basket</button>
    </form>



            </div>

    </article>



BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 15s
4 actionable tasks: 4 executed
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/com.toscrape.books.selenium$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/com.toscrape.books.selenium$
```

Too much is being sent to a `Category` -- it should only handle list items.

The `Catalog` class should only iterate the *categories* of the catalog container:

```
package dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Catalog {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Catalog.class.getName());
    private WebElement container = null;
    private final WebDriver webDriver = null;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//li")
    List<WebElement> catalogElements = null;

    private Catalog() {
    }

    public Catalog(WebDriver webDriver, WebElement container) {
        this.container = container;
        LOG.fine(container.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
        PageFactory.initElements(webDriver, this);
    }

    public void iterateCatalogElements() {
        LOG.info("trying to iterate..");
        LOG.fine(catalogElements.toString());
        ListIterator<WebElement> li = catalogElements.listIterator();
        WebElement listItem = null;
        while (li.hasNext()) {
            listItem = li.next();
            LOG.info(li.next().getTagName());
            LOG.info(li.next().getText());
            Category c = new Category(webDriver, listItem);
        }
    }
}
```

The `Category` class, which only deals with one category:

```
package dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase;

import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class Category {

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName());
    private WebElement container = null;
    private final WebDriver webdriver = null;

    private Category() {
    }

    public Category(WebDriver webDriver, WebElement container) {
        LOG.info("new category..");
        this.container = container;
        PageFactory.initElements(webDriver, container);
        LOG.info(container.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
    }

    public void iterateThisCategory() {
    }
}
```

While `Category` should confirm that the fragments it receives are of the valid form, the real problem is that the `Catalog` instance somehow is sending more than what's in the `HTML` list itself.

For clarity, and pardon the long output, only `HTML` list items **from this list** should be passed from `Catalog` to the `Category` instances (I only changed what was logged to the console):

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/com.toscrape.books.selenium$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/com.toscrape.books.selenium$ gradle clean run

> Task :run
1546179316703   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "/usr/lib/firefox/firefox" "-marionette" "--headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.a0uEgT6zm0Y4"
*** You are running in headless mode.
1546179317387   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: resource://pdf.js/
1546179317392   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid host permission: about:reader*
1546179321898   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 46537
1546179321925   Marionette      WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
Dec 30, 2018 6:15:22 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript warning: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js, line 1: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
Dec 30, 2018 6:15:27 AM dur.bounceme.net.SeleniumBase.Catalog <init>
INFO: 


                    <li>
                        <a href="catalogue/category/books/travel_2/index.html">

                                Travel

                        </a>

                        </li>


                    <li>
                        <a href="catalogue/category/books/mystery_3/index.html">

                                Mystery

                        </a>

                        </li>



..



                    <li>
                        <a href="catalogue/category/books/erotica_50/index.html">

                                Erotica

                        </a>

                        </li>


                    <li>
                        <a href="catalogue/category/books/crime_51/index.html">

                                Crime

                        </a>

                        </li>



BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 15s
4 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 1 up-to-date
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/com.toscrape.books.selenium$
```

Answer (score 1):

This [kinda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53990389/select-all-the-titles-from-basex-with-xpath/53990913#53990913) works:

[image: xpath]

Obviously, that's one result -- I would want to iterate the list for all results.

One angle is just to see what's possible from withing `basex` itself.  I believe it can grab the `html` directly from the [website](http://books.toscrape.com/).  (I'll probably update the answer.)